# sls deploy - command not found when running via google/zx

Tags: javascript, bash, serverless-framework, google-zx

I want to write a simple deploy script with `google/zx` which deploys my `serverless.yml` files. However I always receive this error when trying to:

`/bin/bash: sls deploy --stage test --region eu-west-1 --aws-profile my-profile: command not found`

I can successfully run `sls deploy` in my terminal.

```
import { $ } from 'zx'
import { join } from 'path';
import 'zx/globals'

// Get the environment parameter from the command-line arguments
const environment = process.argv[3] || 'test';
const region = 'eu-west-1';
const profile = 'my-profile';


const components = [
  'system',
  'infra',
];
// Deploy each component with the profile
console.log(`Deploying components to "${environment}" environment with profile "${profile}"...`);
await Promise.all(components.map(async (component) => {
  const command = `sls deploy --stage ${environment} --region ${region} --aws-profile ${profile}`;
  const path = join(__dirname, '..', 'components', component);
  console.log(`Deploying component "${component}"...`);
  await $ `cd ${path} && ${command}`;
}));
```

I run the script in the terminal via : `./deploy.mjs`

Comment: What happens if you specify the full path to `sls`? Perhaps your PATH is wrong in your script.

Comment: then I get: 
`/Users/zlZimon/.nvm/versions/node/v19.2.0/bin/sls deploy --stage play --region eu-west-1 --aws-profile my-profile: No such file or directory`

Comment: I don't know Javascript and zx well enough, but from the error message, I conclude that the whole string "..../sls deploy ...." etc is taken as a single command.  No word splitting seems to be done in `${command}`.

Comment: yea I think you are right, I just don't know the reason :)

Comment: At least I would then add the _javascript_ tag to attract people with good knowledge in Javascript syntax.